# How can I easily install ncview in 17.04?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install ncview on Ubuntu 17.04. Can anyone suggest how I can install it easily?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `synaptic` or

```
sudo apt-get install ncview
```